# USA: cellular plans with domestic roaming

Tags: usa, cellphones, roaming

I'll be spending about 20 days in USA, but across multiple cities on the East and West coasts. What would be a good GSM Sim only mobile plan for this?

I've looked through some data online and it seems like T-mobile is the best choice in prepaid plans. The $30/mo plan with 100 voice minutes and 5 GB of LTE seems like a good plan. However I cannot find any information about domestic roaming charges and domestic data roaming on these plans.

Does anyone know about the domestic roaming charges for T-mobile in the US.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most USA phone plans cover the entire USA, so no domestic roaming countrywide and usually no long distance charges for calls within the USA. The phone company websites usually have coverage maps available online, so you can see where you might not have access.  The blank spots are often areas with simply no coverage, but some maybe served by a small local provider.

Comment: I saw this page: http://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-3299 and it seemed like T-mobile will allow only a small fraction of the available data limit when roaming domestically.

Now, I believe that this cap is only applicable when using another operator instead of T-mobile. Am I right?

Comment: Data plans are so convoluted these days, even the company's own sales people don't fully understand them.  I have not dealt with T-Mobile personally, but have had data plans (both pre-paid and post-paid) through AT&T without any roaming issues or restrictions on their network.

Comment: @darnir As long as you are on the T-Mobile US network (your smartphone will _say_ T-Mobile) then data roaming does not apply, as you are not roaming.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you like to use your phone from abroad.

T-Mobile USA uses a rather strange UMTS frequency bands (1700 MHz AWS). This band isn't supported by most mobile phones. American LTE Bands are generally different than those of the rest of the world. 2G GSM will work with T-Mobile and AT&T.

The only network that supports nationswide UMTS on 2100 MHz (as used in India) is AT&T. The LTE capabilities depends on your phone.

You can check which provider works when you arrive. Search with your phone for network operators. It will list all providers and the supported networks (2G, 3G, 4G).

All plans I used covered the whole USA and even Puerto Rico. So no domnestic roaming.